# Rally Cors issue

Tags: cors, rally

Writing a Simple App , loading a store and displaying via a RAlly grid.
The app worked till last week , however this week it started giving the CORS issue

> 15:58:02.108 App-debug.html:1 Failed to load
>   https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement?start=1&pagesize=200&query=((InProgressDate%20%3E%3D%20%222018-04-07%22)%20AND%20(DirectChildrenCount%20%3D%200))&fetch=Name%2CFormattedID&includePermissions=true&compact=true&project=%2Fproject%2F52627035068&projectScopeUp=false&projectScopeDown=true:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1337' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: are sure that IP is in the index.html ? IP was updated ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Chrome?  There is a longstanding bug where it caches its CORS preflight headers too long which can result in this error.  Usually opening the app in an incognito window or clearing cache and refreshing clears this right up...

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with Chrome..

for some reason , Chrome does not seem to catch any errors and always response with CORS Error.
i ran the code in firefox , isolated the issue and fixed it and when ran the same code in Chrome it worked fine.